# "The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-value'" error in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I've just migrated a Blazor project from Core 3 Preview 6 to Preview 8 and I'm now getting this error:

> The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute
>   'bind-value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or
>   'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like
>   'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.

I've isolated the component that's causing this to happen, and the code certainly seems to `bind-value` set as per the instructions in the error message:

```cs
      <TelerikDropdownList Data="@State.ContainerSizes" 
                           ValueField=@nameof(ContainerSize.ContainerSizeId)
                           TextField=@nameof(ContainerSize.ContainerSizeName)
                           @bind-Value="@ContainerSizeIdNoNull"
                           >
      </TelerikDropdownList>
```

I've tried removing the `@` from `@bind-Value` and changing the capitalisation `@bind-Value`etc. but all to no avail.

What can be causing this?

Comment: A compile-time error is not an exception.

Comment: Good point @HenkHolterman, I've fixed the title accordingly.

Comment: I'd like to know if you have figured out in which cases lowercase value is used vs. uppercase Value. I'm still stumped on this and might open up a question.

Comment: @kanayt I'm afraid not.  I'm not doing as much programming nowadays, so I don't have an answer for that.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It turns out there are at least two causes of this:

#### 1. The component name is now case-sensitive

The answer turns out to be that naming of blazor components is now case-sensitive, and I was missing a capital letter in 'TelerikDropdownList' which should be TelerikDrop**D**ownList.

The change to use case-sensitive names is [documented here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9860) and is also discussed [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9786) and in the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  The idea was to reduce misleading messages, but it's had the consequence of introducing another one, so I've raised [an issue for that on the AspNetCore repo](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13193).

#### 2. You've forgotten the `@using` statement for the component's namespace

You'll also get the same error if you've forgotten or removed the `@using` statement for the component's namespace.  That's very easy to do if you're using ReSharper as it is currently flagging them as unused and offering to remove them.

#### Checking if this is the issue

A good way to check if the compiler has correctly identified your component as a Blazor component rather than a HTML tag is to check the colour coding of the keywords. They will be the same colour if things are working correctly (green in the example below):

[image]

Whereas if the name or namespace are wrong you'll see a mix of colours (note that `Data` and `ValueField` are now a different colour to `TelerikDropdownList`):

[image]

Comment: Also I think you may need to chnage: @bind-Value="@ContainerSizeIdNoNull" to: @bind-Value="ContainerSizeIdNoNull"

Comment: Missing using was the culprit for me

Comment: Case sensitive! Ouch!

Comment: This could also happen if you've misspelled the component name!  Thanks for the tip.  It let me to the correct solution.

Comment: Something else was not defined causing me to get this error for some reason. Fixed another issue which fixed this issue.

Answer (score 26):

“The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-value'” exception in Blazor

I had a similar issue, but the solution was rather easy than intuitive!

Finally I found the information that adding a missing using statement of the used component was helpful. so did I. And it worked!

Despite the component name was shown in *green* (like it is recognized) it wasn't. Only the missing using solved the problem. This is a **missleading** behavior.

So if you have the same problem, check if you're missing a 'using' for the actual component **even** if the component's name is shown in green.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had following parameters:

```
[Parameter]
public string[] BindingValue { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string[]> BindingValueChanged { get; set; }
```

And the binding:

```
<MultiselectDropdownComponent 
@bind-BindingValue="SessionState.MyArray" />
```

Was producing the same error as in subject. I had a `using` statement specified as well..

From the MS documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#binding-with-component-parameters

```
<Child @bind-Year="year" />
```

> The Year parameter is bindable because it has a companion YearChanged event that matches the type of the Year parameter.

> By convention, a property can be bound to a corresponding event handler by including an @bind-{PROPERTY}:event attribute assigned to the handler. <Child @bind-Year="year" /> is equivalent to writing:

```
<Child @bind-Year="year" @bind-Year:event="YearChanged" />
```

So I decided to explicitly specify the `event` and it worked!

```
<MultiselectDropdownComponent 
@bind-BindingValue="SessionState.MyArray"
@bind-BindingValue:event="BindingValueChanged" />
```

**edit:** using `Blazor` WASM and .Net 5

Comment: Bravo!  This did the trick for me.  Everything else above was just fine (using, caps) but I kept getting this message.  So much for depending on implicit behavior.

Comment: This fixed it for me also... However, I was moving from .net 5 to .net 6 - it all worked fine in .net 5, as soon as I migrate to six, I get the error message above. I've now added the explicit reference for the "Changed" event to every use of the component as @alex's answer, and it's fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add that I have have been recently struggling with this error when I was writing a Razor Component Library for a Blazor Project. The reason why I was getting the error was a missing `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms` in the _Imports.razor file in my library.

Unfortunately the error message is so generic, it took me a fair while to track this down. Better error reporting would make this so much easier.

If you're doing something similar to me and you get stuck on this problem, hopefully this will help!

Comment: Thank you! Just learning blazor. It doesn't have to be in the _Important.razor though, it can also be added directly into the component where you want to use it. I guess you can add it to _Imports.razor if you want to have it as a global using.

Answer (score 3):

I changed `@bind-Value` to `@bind-value` (lowercase) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can add another - not obvious pitfall (at least to me).

Fully qualifying the component, and next relying on the using statement to identify the properties does not work. This got added by intellisense.

Not working example:

```
@using WebUI.Components.Modals
<WebUI.Components.Modals.WebUI.Components.Modals.AssetModal @bind-IsVisible="_assetDialogVisible" Asset="_selectedAsset"></WebUI.Components.Modals.WebUI.Components.Modals.AssetModal>
```

Working version:

```
@using WebUI.Components.Modals
<AssetModal @bind-IsVisible="_assetDialogVisible" Asset="_selectedAsset"></AssetModal>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I too had this problem appear in a codebase that I had been actively developing for 6 months. Netcore 7, Telerik UI 4.1, ServiceStack 6.7, etc. I tried @tomRedox solution, and it was already there. I commented it out, and all of my Cannot convert source type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ElementReference' errors then disappeared. However I think in the end the cause of all my issues was because I had one component whose name did not match the file.

I used CustomerSearch, instead of CustomerSearchComp. After that my bind Value  error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the library:

```cs
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns
```

Answer (score 0):

A common place solution which can solve this issue at all places is:

in MainLayout.razor file, include -> @layout TelerikLayout

Then create TelerikLayout.razor file in the same folder (mostly be "Shared folder") and paste below code:

`@inherits LayoutComponentBase`

`<TelerikRootComponent>`
    `@Body`
`</TelerikRootComponent>`

Next, in _imports.razor file include below 2 lines:

`@using Telerik.Blazor`
`@using Telerik.Blazor.Components`

After above 2 steps the issue should be resolved. It makes the package available and overrides in all the files.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because I was coding too early in the morning.

I had renamed my `<InputText>` by accident so make sure the element is named correctly. I named it something like `<InputDescription>`, which doesn't exist, by accident when doing a find and replace.

In my opinion, the error messages you get with the HTML could be a little better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the **Properties** of the component and make sure it's set to **content**:
[image: Right click component]

[image: Set Build Action]

Answer (score 0):

Search for the component name in all solution, and check the component project file if there is an exclusion tag for the component (as my case), and remove it.
This can happen if you comment and then uncomment all files.